# how to get selected node value for treeview using click event in angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs, treeview

i am using directive concept in angularjs to display selected node value for tree view using click event function in angularjs.below is my sample code

Tree.html:

```
<div
  data-angular-treeview="true"
  data-tree-model="roleList"
  data-node-id="roleId"
   data-node-label="roleName"
   data-node-children="children"
    data-ng-click="selectNode(roleList[1])"
    data-node-children="children">
    </div>
```

treeviewcontroller.js:

```
$scope.roleList1 = [
        { "roleName" : "User", "roleId" : "role1", "children" : [
          { "roleName" : "subUser1", "roleId" : "role11", "children" : [] },
          { "roleName" : "subUser2", "roleId" : "role12", "children" : [
            { "roleName" : "subUser2-1", "roleId" : "role121", "children" : [
              { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-1", "roleId" : "role1211", "children" : [] },
              { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-2", "roleId" : "role1212", "children" : [] }
            ]}
          ]}
        ]},

        { "roleName" : "Admin", "roleId" : "role2", "children" : [] },

        { "roleName" : "Guest", "roleId" : "role3", "children" : [] }



      ];
```

Treeview.js:

```
    scope.selectNode = function(val)
    {
    alert(val.roleName);
    }



output:
user
      subuser1
      subuser1-1
 Admin
     subadmin1
```

from this output in alert place 'Admin' will be dispalyed by click on Admin node.but i want to display dynamically selected node value in click event function.please suggest me how to do this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In order to dynamically select node of the tree I did following:

Let's say you want to select first (top, [0]) element of your tree.
so first add data-tree-id="myTreeId" to your HTML:

```
<div
    data-angular-treeview="true"
    data-tree-model="roleList"
    data-node-id="roleId"
    data-node-label="roleName"
    data-node-children="children"
    data-ng-click="selectNode(roleList[1])"
    data-node-children="children"
    data-tree-id="myTreeId">
</div>
```

than in Controller:

`$scope.roleList1[0].selected = "selected";
$scope.myTreeId.currentNode = $scope.roleList1[0];`

Comment: Thanks a lot ramsesus. got a clue from ur answer.

Answer (score -1):

In Tree.html :

Add line :
`data-tree-id="mytree"`

Modify data-ng-click event :
`data-ng-click="selectNode(mytree.currentNode.roleName)"`

In Treeview.js :
`scope.selectNode = function(val) { alert(val); }`

Comment: i am doing above changes also but still i am getting undefined value in Treeview.js.

Comment: I have created a plunker `http://plnkr.co/edit/RuUFemqpouPEFIcBBIXh?p=preview` .Please let me know if this what you were looking for

Comment: it is working only for using controller but i am using directive then i am getting undefined value in Treeview.js

Comment: Can you please provide some plunker

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/BVdnb20S6dPwCLsdNioo?p=catalogue so please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: No output is coming in the above plunker. Can you please re-check.